# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Entity is not mapped

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I'm facing weird issues when I'm trying to run a spring boot application packaged as a fat jar.

The application works perfectly with Eclipse and with `mvn spring-boot:run` but when I use `java -jar myjar` the hibernate entities are not mapped.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Entity is not mapped
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
```

I know that `mvn spring-boot:run` is different because it changes the classpath but is there a way to run it with verbose so I can see what the classpath is so that I can use `java -jar` with something similar?

When I print `System.getProperty("java.class.path");`

I get the following

```
 Classpath:/usr/local/apache-maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
```

and when I run it from `java -jar myJar.jar`, I get `myJar.jar` so that's probably why it's not working.

Here are the pom files :

Api (containing the main class)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>jar-with-all-dependencies</classifier>
                            <mainClass>
                              ${main-class-path}
                            </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Service (containing the hibernate logic)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org-springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org-springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${org-springframework-data.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
        <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
       <version>${org-springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-media-json-jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${apt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.foo")
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (!argurmentsValid(args)) {
            return;
        }

        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

Here's the configuration inside the api

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApiConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    public static final String CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "api.properties";

    public ApiConfiguration() {
        register(com.foo.api.v1.controllers.aController.class);
    }
}
```

Here's the configuration inside the service library

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foo.service")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean () {
        return new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

and I have regular hibernate entities inside com.foo.service.

I package the jar with `mvn clean install` then I run it with `java -jar jar-with-all-dependencies.jar`

Comment: Can you show the main Spring Boot class and the entity you are trying to access? That error is thrown when you are trying to store or retrieve an object from the database, but the configuration does not define the object class as an entity.

Comment: @Yserbius updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know some details to be able to help you:

1- How did you package to fat jar?
2- How do you run it?

Springboot cannot be packaged like any other application in a fat jar, like you mentionned, it changes the classpath to be able to use springboot auto-config correctly.

I have recently created a fatjar for springboot app and it works well, but I had to use a repackaging gradle plugin to reassemble the jar correctly.  The plugin was made by spring and you probably have the same with maven.

Have you looked here?:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html

ALSO

Remember that Eclipse do some classpath magic that gets the job done even if you misconfigured your app.

- Where did you specify the EntityScan path?  The problem could be spring don't scan the package
- Did you forgot to pass parameters to java -jar  like spring.profiles.active ?

For fatJar you need:

- Special springboot packaging (use plugin)
- specifiy main class (you have done that)
- Pass required system parameters (profiles, etc.)

Regarding the last point, I have noticed that springboot packaging didn't consider my -D parameters when running using java -jar, I had to use the JavaExec gradle plugin.

Comment: I have updated the question with the missing information. I use the spring-boot-maven-plugin to package the api and I have tried with EntityScan without any success

Comment: I am not sure if EntityScan is required

Comment: There some mix up in the configuration I think. in the ServiceConfiguration class, you add a componentScan and if I understand well, it was to specify wich package contains the entities right?  ComponentScan scans components and Service annotations mostly.  You need to add EntityScan and specify packages in basePackages property of this annotation to point to your entities. You must also have annotated your entity class with @Entity and specified a name for the database table if your classname doesn't match.

Comment: I have tried with EntityScan and the basePackage but without luck. I'm convinced it has something to do with the way it's packaged because it works in eclipse and with mvn spring-boot:run. it probably calls the jar with a different classpath. I wish I could find out what it does

Comment: Eclipse add some magic to the classpath you can't rely on it when executing with java -jar.

Comment: You can try another thing, have you check if the repackage goal is called?  Try executing only the repackage goal and see if the jar is different.